# Connection state always waiting

Tags: flutter, dart

While fetching data from database in flutter snapShot.ConnectionState is always waiting and the circular progress indicator keeps on loading.

I am not getting any errors and I am using FutureBuilder to build my widget.

Class where I build my widget

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import '../providers/event_provider.dart';

    class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: Provider.of<EventProviders>(context).fetchAndSetEvents(),
          builder: (ctx, dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return Consumer<EventProviders>(
                child: Text('Not found'),
                builder: (ctx, eventData, ch) {
                  if (eventData.events.length <= 0) {
                    return ch;
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: eventData.events.length,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                        return Container(
                          child: Text(eventData.events[index].eventName),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

My future class

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetEvents() async {
      final dataList = await DBHelper.getData('user_events');
      _events = dataList
          .map(
            (data) => EventProvider(
              eventName: data['event'],
              eventDate: data['date'],
              id: data['id'],
            ),
          )
          .toList();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Some help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Set listen: false

```
future: Provider.of<EventProviders>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetEvents(),
```